# Topology generation

Tags: general-topology, definition

What does it mean for a topology to be generated? For example $X=\mathbb{R}$ be topology generated by $[a,b)$. Isn't the topology a collection of open sets? $[a,b)$ is not open though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a set, and let $\mathscr{S}$ be any family of subsets of $X$. Then there is a unique topology $\mathscr{T}$ on $X$ such that

1. $\mathscr{S}\subseteq\mathscr{T}$, and
2. if $\mathscr{T}'$ is any topology on $X$ such that $\mathscr{S}\subseteq\mathscr{T}'$, then $\mathscr{T}\subseteq\mathscr{T}'$.

In other words, $\mathscr{T}$ is the smallest topology containing each set in the collection $\mathscr{S}$. We say that $\mathscr{T}$ is the *topology generated by* $\mathscr{S}$. $\mathscr{S}$ is said to be a [*subbase*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase) (or *subbases*) for the topology $\mathscr{T}$.

In your example I strongly suspect that you’ve incorrectly paraphrased the statement that’s bothering you: I’m reasonably sure that what was actually described was the topology on $\Bbb R$ generated not by a single set $[a,b)$, but by the collection of **all** sets of the form $[a,b)$, where $a,b\in\Bbb R$ and $a<b$. In other words,

$$\mathscr{S}=\Big\{[a,b):a,b\in\Bbb R\text{ and }a<b\Big\}\;.$$

It turns out that this $\mathscr{S}$ is already a [base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_%28topology%29) (or basis) for a topology on $\Bbb R$, so the non-empty open sets in the topology that it generates are simply the sets that are unions of intervals of the form $[a,b)$. This topology is called the *Sorgenfrey* or *lower-limit* topology on $\Bbb R$, and the resulting space is known as the [*Sorgenfrey line*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_line); it’s a fairly important example in general topology.

It’s true that sets of the form $[a,b)$ are not open **in the usual topology on** $\Bbb R$, but that’s completely irrelevant: you’re defining a new topology on $\Bbb R$, one that is in many ways very different from the usual one.

Comment: So, in this case $\mathscr{S}$ will be family of open subsets of $X$

Comment: @JamesBond: No, the family of open subsets of $X$ is equal to the collection of all **unions** of members of $\mathscr{S}$. For example, the set $[0,1)\cup[2,3)$ is open in the Sorgenfrey topology, but it’s not in $\mathscr{S}$. For that matter, $(0,1)$ is open in the Sorgenfrey topology: it’s the union of the intervals $[x,1)$ with $0<x<1$. And it’s not in $\mathscr{S}$ either.

Comment: I see. If I understand this correctly is it true that: $[0,1]\cup[2,3)$ is open in Sorgenfrey topology because it's the union of open sets  $[0,1]$ and $[2,3)$ which are in $\mathscr{I}$ and for (0,1) its the infinite union of open sets of the form [x,1)

Comment: @JamesBond: No, $[0,1]$ isn’t open in the Sorgenfrey topology: there is no set of the form $[a,b)$ that contains $1$ and is a subset of $[0,1]$. But $[0,1)$ is open in the Sorgenfrey topology.

Comment: That was my mistake. I meant $[0,1)$ and not $[0,1]$

Comment: @JamesBond: Then what you wrote was fine (though you should make sure that you understand why $[0,1]$ isn’t open in the Sorgenfrey top. and $(0,1)$ is).

Comment: Yes, I do. $[0,1]$ is not open as I cannot find any union/intersection of sets $[a,b)$ which will give me $[0,1]$

Answer (score 1):

*Open set* is another name for an element in the family of sets that is called *topology*. Any collection of subsets of $\Bbb R$ can form a topology as long as certain properties are satisfied. On the other hand, any collection of sets $\mathcal C$ generates a topology $\tau$, namely the smallest topology such that $\mathcal C\subseteq\tau$. It can be constructed by taking arbitrary unions of finite intersections of the sets in $\cal C.$

So if you want $[a,b)$ to be an open set, first take finite intersections of such intervals. But these are again of the form $[a,b)$. So the open sets, i.e. the elements of the topology generated by the family $\{[a,b)\mid a,b\in\Bbb R\}$ will simply be the unions of intervals of the form $[a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

It is open if you declare it to be :) So you have to look at all unions and finite intersections of such sets (for all $a<b$) to get the topology.